# handlebars.js - difference between #each block and #block

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

What's the difference between these two handlebars.js templates?

```
{{#myblock}}

  {{this}}

{{/myblock}}
```

and

```
{{#each myblock}}

  {{this}}

{{/each}}
```

Given that there is no helper defined for "myblock", the two templates (from what I can see) operate and output the same. Is there any difference between the two templates besides readability?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to understand this is whatever that comes after the hash sign (#) is a helper. A helper is function which handlebars calls with the optional paramaters which are derived from what follows the helper declaration in template.

```
{{#each myblock}}

  {{this}}

{{/each}}
```

In case of #each it calls the functions which iterates over the argument provided 'myblock' in this case (which will be array in almost all cases) and will output the content generated for each element. **this** becomes the each elements in that iterations.

Similarly in the first example myblock becomes a helper since it follows the # sign.

```
{{#myblock}}

  {{this}}

{{/myblock}}
```

Now since there is no predefined helper with name myblock, you can create the custom helper using Handlebars.registerHelper() like following.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myblock', function(context, options) {
  return options.fn(context);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question may be a bit vague. Given that there is no helper defined for "myblock", the two templates (from what I can see) operate and output the same. Is there any difference between the two templates besides readability?

Comment: I guess thats some new feature added to Handlebars where you can iterate the array with the name. I am not sure of it though. Trying to find the references to this....

Comment: It's a feature in Mustache (which handlebars builds on to). It's in the manual under "Sections" here: http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html I've not used either solution before so I wouldn't know when it was implemented.